# jQuery delay not working

Tags: jquery

```
$('.transparent').removeClass('transparent').delay(2000).addClass('not_transparent').delay(4000)
```

I have a div that is semi transparent and then want to switch it to not transparent. But the jQuery .delay(); method doesn't seem to work here. I've tried .fadeIn(); instead and that works with a delay but it doesn't work the changing classes.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

[`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) is used for items that are part of a `queue`, like animations. A simple `addClass` is not queued.

You could use `setTimeout`.

```
var trans = $('.transparent').removeClass('transparent');
setTimeout(function() {
    trans.addClass('not_transparent');
}, 2000);
```

As an alternative, you could add the non-queued item to the queue using [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/), though I think a `setTimeout` would be better.

```
$('.transparent').removeClass('transparent').delay(2000).queue(function(nxt) {
      $(this).addClass('not_transparent');
      nxt();
});
```

Comment: why do you think setTimeout is better?

Comment: @Sam: It is just very simple, and a native implementation. I don't know what sort of overhead is involved with `queue()`, but I'm certain it is quite a bit more than the `setTimeout`.

Comment: why do you call the function from within itself?

nxt();

Comment: +1 gave both solutions a go, was initially planning on using jQuery solution but found that it only worked the first time the event was triggered. Second solution works fine.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old question, but there's still a lot of traffic coming here from google so I'll add my two cents;

You could use something like -

```js
$('.transparent').fadeIn().delay(500).queue(function(){
  $('.transparent').addClass('yourclass');
});
```

You can pass a function to the queue in order to execute them after the delay. Have been using this myself for very similar examples.

Answer (score 1):

`.delay()` does not work with the `.addClass()` tag outside of a function so just use:

```
delay();
function delay(){
     $('.pgtitle').delay(5000).fadeIn(0).addClass('animated bounceInDown');
}
```

Comment: I was struggling with `$(#idOfTheThing).delay(1000).show();` Then I saw your answer and : `$(#idOfTheThing).delay(1000).fadeIn();` works like a charm