# jQuery each() with a delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I would like an element to fade in and wait half a second, then fade the next in etc...

My code:

```
$('.comment').each(function() {                 
                    $(this).css({'opacity':0.0}).animate({
                        'opacity':1.0
                    }, 450).delay(500);
                });
```

I'm obviously doing something really silly.... (I hope)... My question is: Is this even possible? if not - can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanking you!

Comment: What is your code doing, as opposed to what you want it to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add pause between each iteration of jQuery .each()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202403/how-to-add-pause-between-each-iteration-of-jquery-each)

Comment: I never saw that question.... However, this question does have different answers though... Worth keeping it for others to have different suggestions

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Or, something like this:

```
$.each($('.comment'), function(i, el){

    $(el).css({'opacity':0});

    setTimeout(function(){
       $(el).animate({
        'opacity':1.0
       }, 450);
    },500 + ( i * 500 ));

});
```

demo => http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/9uS56/

Answer (score 13):

try something like this

```
$(this).find('#results').children().each(function(index){
        $(this).delay(500 * index).slideDown(500);
})
```

Comment: Awesome answer. I was trying to do the same and the trick of multiplying the delay with the index worked great. Thanks!

Comment: For others that only saw the incomplete headline "jQuery each() with a delay" (deals with animations). Only with animations you can use delay. If you go over your children and you want e.g. **trigger a click, delay will not work**. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/4544126/1066234

Answer (score 5):

Try this out:

```
var time = 500;
$('.comment').each(function() {                 
     var $this  = $(this);
    function delayed() {
         $this.css({'opacity':0.0}).animate({
                    'opacity':1.0
                }, 450);
     }
    setTimeout( delayed , time );
    time += 500;
 });
```

Answer (score 4):

or using `.next()` and a callback function:

```
// create a function to fade in the comment block
function showit(item){

    // animate the fade effect (and any other required)
    item.animate({opacity:1},450,function(){

        // after completing the animation, call the
        // showit function with the next comment block
        showit(item.next('.comment'))

    })

}

// set the opacity of comment blocks to 0 and
// select the first one, then call showit to
// initialise animation loop
showit( $('.comment').css({opacity:0}).eq(0) )
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rJnnZ/

I think this is a better solution, because it waits until the previous animation is finished, before moving onto the next, rather than calculating the timer beforehand, which can become un-synchronised under heavy CPU usage, or various other circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

This function will iterate through every element in the collection (in this example `$comments`) and fade in all of them. Every animation will start when the previous one has finished.

```
var $comments=$('.comment');

(function fadeIterator($collection, index) {
    $collection.eq(index).fadeIn(1000, function () {
        fadeIterator($collection, index++);
    });
}($comments, 0));
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/sUREn/1/)