# jQuery CSS Keyframing

Tags: jquery, css, animation, keyframe

Trying to make a simple repeated keyframed animation with jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').mouseover(function() {
        var animateloop = 0;

        $(this).mouseout(function(){
            animateloop++;
        });

        while (animateloop !== 1) {
            $(this).delay(40).css(
                'font-family':'Homestead'
            ).delay(40).css(
                'font-family':'Arvo'
            );
        }
    });
});
```

I thought this code above would work, but I don't understand jQuery all that much so I can't make it work.

You can see this a JSFIDDLE here:

> http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKyle/nPVxb/

Comment: It's not doing anything, I want it to switch fonts, did you look at the jsfiddle?

Comment: its not switching the fonts because chances are the user doesn't have the font (me being one of them). Its switching colors for me

Comment: I have the fonts in a separate resource thats being imported through jsfiddle. I know thats not the problem

Comment: Why is it changing colors though?

Comment: because I'm also using a webkit animation

Answer (score 1):

one error first:

```
$(this).delay(40).css(
   'font-family':'Homestead'
)
```

the colon：

```
$(this).delay(40).css(
   'font-family','Homestead'
)
```

Comment: Okay that just crashed the browser

Comment: Mine Too. I think its just to much for a browser to check the font-family in a loop.

Comment: yeah,because the while statement has no endless

Answer (score 1):

This works.

```
$(this).delay(400).css({
   'font-family':'Homestead'
});
```

The problem is your .delay() and not your .css()

.delay() is used for items that are part of a queue, like animations.

You can use .queue() or setTimeout()

Read more on this thread: [jQuery delay not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544126/jquery-delay-not-working)

Something like :

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').mouseover(function() {

        setTimeout(function() {changefont('arial');}, 400);
        setTimeout(function() {changefont('courrier new');}, 800);
        setTimeout(function() {changefont('impact');}, 1200);

    });
});


function changefont(fontname) {
    $('body').css({'font-family':fontname});
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nPVxb/74/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want an infinite loop and are working within the scope of an object...

```
...
animation : ["first","second","third","etc"],
frameDelay : 400,
frameIndex : 0,
animationTimer : null,
start : function() {
    // remember the scope of this object.
    var handle = this;
    // start the animation.
    handle._nextFrame(handle);
},
_nextFrame : function(handle) {
    // TODO: use frameIndex to render stuff... such as:
    var animation = handle.animation[frameIndex];
    $('body').html('<p>'+animation+'</p>');
    // count your frames. You might add stuff to the sequence elsewhere.
    var numFrames = handle.animation.length;
    frameIndex = frameIndex < numFrames ? frameIndex++ : 0;
    handle.animationTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
        handle._nextFrame(handle); }, handle.frameDelay);
},
_destroy : function() {
    var handle = this;
    clearTimeout(handle.animationTimer);
}...
```

Notes:
I use an old school method of underscoring private functions on an interface. You don't have to name your variables that way, and they are not private.

You will notice that I store "this" into "handle". You can't always rely on the scope of this, such as calling an object function from an event bubble, calling it from a public interface, or referencing a function internally to the object. So I just do this as a convention.

Put this code into your object, call the 'start' function, and it should continue doing its thing until you leave the page. Also, make sure to clean up your recursive timeouts, less you get an error on page refresh or page navigation.