# jQuery delay to work with append()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't make the delay function of jQuery works with `append` function. What is wrong? Is there a way to make it work? I want to avoid using `setTimeout` directly to make it more easy to follow for the customer, who will maintain it himself, without any experience.

My code:

```
$('#chatwindow').append('test').delay(2000).append('test');
```

In this code, I get 'testtest' printed at the same time, `delay` is ignored.

Comment: Are you trying to append test twice?

Comment: Yes, test being a string, it should be added twice, you can replace it by any text you want.

Comment: You could search for it in the first place :) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544126/jquery-delay-not-working

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is because [`delay(2000)`](http://api.jquery.com/delay) queues the `fx` queue by default, which `append()` is never part of.

Instead, you can specifically queue `append()` on it using the [`queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue) function.

```
$('#chatwindow').append('test').delay(2000).queue(function (next) {
    $(this).append('test');
    next();
});
```

You can see an example of this working here; http://jsfiddle.net/mj8qC/

However, I agree with @ascii-lime's comment; I expect the customer will have more chance understanding `setTimeout` as it's a fundamental part of JavaScript, unlike `delay()`, which confuses *many* users (from experience on questions asked on StackOverflow).

<sup>FWIW, this question triggered me to write [a blog post](http://www.mattlunn.me.uk/blog/2012/06/jquery-delay-not-working-for-you/) on the uses of `delay()`; it goes into more detail than this answer, and might be great further reading for others.</sup>

Comment: While there are several answers here, showing how to work with `queues in jquery` is such a huge piece of information. Definitely the best answer.

Comment: +1 append By default is not queued, it is executed immediately, because it is not used for animations. This will add it to the queue. Whether this is simpler to understand than `setTimeout` for the OP's client is debatable, but this answer is definitely the most informative.

Comment: You can also quote the jQuery docs on it :) "The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases."

Comment: I'm among the ones very wary about this `delay` function. It looks at first like a generic magic function and then you read the jquery source code to understand and see its usages are very limited. They should probably have called it clearly to show it's mainly for delaying an effect.

Answer (score 3):

`delay()` is a tricky function that can't be use with anything : it's mainly made for effects (it returns immediately, it doesn't block the javascript execution flow).

From [the doc](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) :

> It can be used with the standard effects queue or with a custom queue

(so you have to use a custom queue if you're not using the fx queue)

Use setTimeout in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The return from delay is immediate. Nothing in your code suggest that the reurn should wait. You need to use setTimeout for the engine to wait..