# jQuery: click indicator on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

It may be obvious I'm very new to web development.  Anyway, I'm trying to create a click event on a div and change its background color.  But I want the background to change back to its original color after the click up.  Here is what I have:

jQuery:

```
$('.details1').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('on').delay(200).toggleClass('on');
});
```

css:

```
div.on {
    background: #F78181;
}
```

I don't exactly want a millisecond delay, that's just for debugging.  Just want to change background on click down and up.  Thanks.

Comment: Jquery delay is used for items that are part of a queue, like animation. toggleClass is apparently not a queued event. I usually use setTimeout(function(),200);

Comment: I actually tried that just now, for some reason I'm getting an undefined function error on `setTimeout()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544126/jquery-delay-not-working

Comment: Do you want to change the color back after 200ms or when the click is finished?

Comment: Can you update question with the revised javascript?   Can't troubleshoot error you posted to comments with out reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `setTimeout()` function for your problem instead of delay()

```
$('.details1').click(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){ $('#clrd').toggleClass('on'); }, 200);
    });
```

you can change the time (milliseconds) as per your need. In this case it is 200ms

Check this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hbzm8q45/)**