# Jquery Modal on click add class then remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This bit of code is supposed to add a class and then with a delay remove the div entirely. It just jumps to deleting the div. Any ideas why?

The HTML

```
 <!-- modal conent-->
    <div class="modal" id="modal">
     <div class="modal-content ">
      <h1>Tricks Are 4 Kids</h1>
     <p>Ok so my modal doesn't look like this one, but this is it boiled down. Can I write the JS better??? ....</p>
       <button href="#" class="close" id="close" >X</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
 <!-- page conent-->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper" >I am a div with all the page conent. lalalalala</div>
```

The CSS

```
.red {background:red;}
```

The jQuery

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $( "#close" ).click(function() {
        $("#modal").addClass("red").delay(800).queue
        $("#modal").remove();
    });
```

Codepen https://codepen.io/Ella33/pen/GjQZRP

Comment: Wouldn't be better to make a setTimeout function within the click function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery delay not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544126/jquery-delay-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $( "#close" ).click(function() {
    $("#modal").addClass("red");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#modal").remove();
    }, 800); 
});
```