# How to delay a JQuery window reload?

Tags: jquery

What am I missing?  I can't seem to delay this even though the syntax seems correct.

```
window.location.reload(true).delay(800);//true= hard refresh
```

Comment: Can't you just use the `setTimeout` thing?

Comment: Check out this answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544126/jquery-delay-not-working

Comment: `setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(true); },800);`

Comment: Per https://api.jquery.com/delay/ `delay()` "set(s) a timer to delay execution of subsequent items in the queue".  Your `reload` comes before `delay`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reload()` doesn't return *anything* that I know of; certainly not  a jQuery object, or any object on which `delay()` could be called.

Not that it matters - `reload()` takes effect immediately.

You want to use `setTimeout()` to delay the actual call to `reload()`

```
setTimeout( 
  function() {
    window.location.reload(true);
  }, 800);
```

Comment: even if it returned something it would not work as delay is for delaying the next queue element and not the previous.