# jQuery issue (Delay and Order)

Tags: javascript, jquery, slide

I am trying to learn jQuery. I’ve tried to make the "slideUp" to happen first and then the "removeClass" and so on but, it doesn't seem to work.

Another issue is that if I click on the same icon that is already selected, the .delay works but not in the other cases.

[Link to jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gustavgesar/2bv4seh1/86/)

```
$(".icon ").click(function() {
  $(".text").slideUp(1000).delay(800);
  $(".icon").removeClass("selected");
  $(".icon").addClass("unselected")
  $(this).removeClass("unselected");
  $(this).addClass("selected");
  $(".text").eq($(this).index()).slideDown(1000);
});
```

Comment: `delay()` is not a replacement for `setTimeout`.  And afaik, addClass/removeClass are not based on the internal queues that jQuery keeps for animations, so they would not be delayed by such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the updated jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/2bv4seh1/113/

```
$(".icon").click(function() {
  $(".text").slideUp(500).delay(500);
  $(".icon").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).toggleClass("selected");
  $(".text").eq($(this).index()).delay(500).queue(function(nxt) {
      $(this).slideDown(300);
      nxt();
})

});
```

.delay() is used for items that are part of a queue, like animations. A simple addClass is not queued. : -
[jQuery delay not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544126/jquery-delay-not-working)

Answer (score 2):

Try writing the code inside the slideUp callback function, like this:

```
$(".icon ").click(function() {
  var _this = $(this);
  $(".text").slideUp(1000, function(){
      $(".icon").removeClass("selected");
      $(".icon").addClass("unselected")
      _this.removeClass("unselected");
      _this.addClass("selected");
      $(".text").eq($(this).index()).slideDown(1000);
  }).delay(800);
});
```