# Why won't this change from red to white after 0.5 seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a memory game in JavaScript and am doing good so far. I am trying to go from Red to white in 0.5 seconds and this is the code I have so far.

```
$("#go").click(function () {
    $("#red").css("background-color", "red", function () {
        $("#red").css("background-color", "white").delay(0050);
    });
});
```

Someone told me to do setTimeOut but I do not understand that yet as I am a beginner in JavaScript. Please help me, thanks!

Comment: `0050`  **== 50 milliseconds**

Comment: Read more about setTimeout in the link, easy concept that would help you with your request - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Comment: @MisterJojo More like `40` (it's in octal, since there are leading zeroes)

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/delay/), `delay` is in miliseconds.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery delay not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544126/jquery-delay-not-working)

Comment: @blex , you're right, it's 40. I prefer octal values written this way `0o50`  -- but I don't think the PO did it on purpose

Comment: Yes thank u everyone

Answer (score 1):

I thought such a solution:

```js
$("#go").click(function () {
  $("#red").css("background-color", "red").delay(500).queue(function (next) { 
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");next(); 
  });
});
```

```css
#red{
  display:block;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
#go {
  height:30px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="go">Go</button>
<div id="red"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This should set it to 0.5 seconds if JS is not using strict mode. I would recommend to test both of the below.

```
$("#go").click(function () {
$("#red").css("background-color", "red", function () {
    $("#red").css("background-color", "white").delay(0764);
});
```

});

If js is using strict mode, this will be 0.5s

```
$("#go").click(function () {
$("#red").css("background-color", "red", function () {
    $("#red").css("background-color", "white").delay(0500);
});
```

});

As people have mentioned in the comments, 0050 is 5 milliseconds in strict mode.

If not in strict mode 0.5s = 0764

Comment: No, `0050` is **40** milliseconds. The leading zeros make JS treat it as if it's in octal base, not decimal. So `0500` is actually 320 ms. Try to `console.log(0500)`

Comment: The problem the OP is refering to is that the change to the CSS is not delayed (it does not wait for 0050 whatever), it is instant. They did not get to this point.

Comment: @blex - I understand now, I've updated my answer, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: You're overcomplicating things! Just use decimal: `500`. That's it. No need for weird workarounds. I was just pointing out a side-effect of having leading zeros. Just don't add one

Comment: won't work, jQuery delay need queue method